# Apache Spark Convert collection of RDD to single RDD JAVA

Tags: java, collections, apache-spark, rdd, hadoop2

I have following RDD in my Java Code.

```
(1, List(1596, 1617, 1929, 2399, 2674))
(2, List(1702, 1785, 1933, 2054, 2583, 2913))
(3, List(1982, 2002, 2048, 2341, 2666))
```

What I am trying to do is to create another RDD. The contents should look like this.(not necessarily in same order)

```
1596
1617
1929
2399
2674
1702
1785
1933
2054
2583
2913
1982
2002
2048
2341
2666
```

I am not sure how do transform one RDD `(JavaRDD<ArrayList<String>>)` with collection of Objects to single RDD `(JavaRDD<String>)` with all objects in it. I would highly appreciate if anyone could point me to some JAVA resource.

Comment: This will do in scala. `val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(List((1, List(1596, 1617, 1929, 2399, 2674)),(2, List(1702, 1785, 1933, 2054, 2583, 2913)),(3, List(1982, 2002, 2048, 2341, 2666))))
val rdd2 = rdd1.flatMap(x => x._2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same in scala as follows

```
val data = List((1, List(1596, 1617, 1929, 2399, 2674)),
    (2, List(1702, 1785, 1933, 2054, 2583, 2913)),
    (3, List(1982, 2002, 2048, 2341, 2666)))

val rdd_data = sc.parallelize(data)
val rdd_flattened = rdd_data.flatMap((index, value) => value)
```